# Power Source Symbol -- Which to use (Arrow, Bar, Circle, etc.)?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, symbol, source

I'm wondering if there is anyone out there with a definitive answer to why and/or what standard would call out the usage of the different voltage sources.  There are Bars, Arrows, Dots, Waves, etc. I have in the past defined this, but I'm wondering if there are actual standards that also define it.

What I've used in the past is:

- Wave: AC power source
- Bar: DC Power Source (regulated)
- Circle: DC Power source (unregulated)
- Arrow: no idea...

If anyone has any reference to something more concrete, I would love to hear it (and bonus if there's actually reasoning to why we have so many available).

[image]

Update: Picture added.

Comment: Can you provide any pictures of what you're talking about? IEEE Std 91/91a, IEC 60617, and ANSI Y32.2-1975 all have their methods of keeping consistent symbol usage.

Comment: This is why there are so many standards: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Or this std.  https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/circuit_diagram.png. Arrow in circle is a current source

Comment: This is where trust issues arises from, tons of standards, if I were you I would just use either of them and then write in plain text nearby what it is. - At my university I had one teacher who preferred the bar one, another teacher who preferred the arrow, both of the teachers were talking about the exact same kind of voltage source.

Comment: It doesn't matter because nobody who reads the schematics is aware of the standards anyway (if any). I have not actually seen the wavy line before. But the circle triangle and horizontal line (or I guess you could call it a 'T')  are all familiar.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at IEEE Std 315, "Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams". Of course, this is a U.S. standard and other countries may have their own standards.

Comment: That standard only calls out common nets (i.e. 0 Volts potential).  I'm looking for DC power nets specifically...

Comment: No, a "common net" does not mean "0 volts potential". It is any net that has a number of common connections but you don't want to draw the actual wire.